# Can I get request header and response header for web service function?

Tags: rest, session, cxf, cxfrs

I am using Java with Apache CXF to write the backend for AngularJS (single-page web site).   In my REST service, I need access to the header of the http request (i.e. parameters and cookies) and I need access to the response header also (i.e. parameters and cookies).   The main reason for this is security, authentication purposes and session management.   Those are important reasons.

Is there a way of getting both of these structures in Apach CXF RESTfull code?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject request by using `@Context` [javax.ws.rs.core.Context]

```
  public Response myRest(@Context HttpServletRequest request /*, other parameters if you have like @QueryParam */ ){
    request.getCookies();
    request.getUserPrincipal();
}
```

You can set cookie or header in response as bellow

```
ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(); //Response.status(500) either way
builder.cookie(arg0);
builder.header(arg0, arg1);
return bulider.build();
```

Comment: Great solution for the request access. Does it work with HttpServletResponse also? Since servlet handler has both HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse parameters, so it's fair to assume that we can also get the a reference to the response the same way. But nobody wants to put these two parameters in the interface of web service functions. Maybe creating an in-line class where these parameters are injected in the constructor parameters might do the trick! It's worth trying!